# cocos2d-x CCDirector, pause/resume vs stopAnimation/startAnimation

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

First, I need to say, all the following is based on cocos2d-x-2.1.4.

In HelloCpp project of cocos2d-x, you can see it calls `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();` in `void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()`([click here to check](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/cocos2d-x-2.1.4/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp#L81)).

It supposes to stop the animation when app is inactive. And it perform perfectly in iOs.

But in Android, after I called this `stopAnimation()`, the elements which were running animations will start to blink. And it displayed worse as the device had lower performance.

I then tried to use `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause()`, it performed not bad, the animations stopped and **NOT** blinked.

So I want to know what the difference between these two method.

In [`CCDirector.h`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/cocos2d-x-2.1.4/cocos2dx/CCDirector.h), we can see these code:

```
/** Pauses the running scene.
 The running scene will be _drawed_ but all scheduled timers will be paused
 While paused, the draw rate will be 4 FPS to reduce CPU consumption
 */
void pause(void);

/** Stops the animation. Nothing will be drawn. The main loop won't be triggered anymore.
 If you don't want to pause your animation call [pause] instead.
 */
virtual void stopAnimation(void) = 0;
```

Here it says, "If you don't want to pause your animation call [pause] instead.", but in fact, I could pause animation if I called `pause()`, so I was confused.

And in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008141/cocos2d-x-game-crashes-when-entered-background), it said the app would crash if called `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();` in `void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()`. But I had tested it by myself, it did not crash at this version in both iOs and Android.

So, I thought what would happened if I use `pause()` instead of `stopAnimation()`.

Then I did some test. Finally I got the result, `stopAnimation()` performed better than `pause()` in iOs, but in reverse in Android.

So I wanted to change my code to this:

```
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();
#elif (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();
#endif
}

void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();
#elif (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();
#endif
}
```

Now can anyone give me some suggestion? Or if it is not good, tell me why.

Answer (score 2):

Pause will keep drawing and presenting the framebuffer, but at a very low framerate (4 fps).

StopAnimation stops drawing altogether. At this point it is not defined what will happen to the display - on iOS it tends to just "freeze" but depending on GL driver implementation, the blinking you experience would also be a possible outcome. This is when double or triple buffering keeps cycling through the framebuffers, but only one of them contains the contents of the frame cocos2d has drawn last.

Stop animation is only meant for situations where the app enters background or is otherwise hidden, for example by presenting another view on top of it. Otherwise use pause.

Perhaps you just need to run startAnimation again when the app enters foreground to prevent the blinking? It certainly should not be required to use pause on one platform and stopAnimation on another.

Comment: Run `startAnimation` indeed make blink disappear.But in pause state, it would blink, and I can't find other way to solve it.