# Cocos2d-x game crash on android when onResume

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

I am trying to solve `onResume` error in my game created by Cocos2d-x. When i go background and come back to game then game is crashed. and log-cat are as followed.

```
11:49:10.997 E/cocos2d-x: cocos2d: warning, Director::setProjection() failed because size is 0
11:49:11.001 D/Cocos2dxActivity: onWindowFocusChanged() hasFocus=true
11:49:11.020 D/FA: Connected to remote service
11:49:11.020 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
11:49:11.062 D/Cocos2dxActivity: onPause()
11:49:11.064 D/AudioFocusManager: abandonAudioFocus succeed!
11:49:11.077 D/Cocos2dxActivity: onWindowFocusChanged() hasFocus=false
11:49:11.080 V/FA: onActivityCreated
11:49:11.087 I/SDKBOX_CORE: Sdkbox Droid starting.
11:49:11.087 I/SDKBOX_CORE: Sdkbox got VM.
11:49:11.087 I/SDKBOX_CORE: Initialize is called more than once.
11:49:11.094 D/Cocos2dxActivity: model=MotoE2
11:49:11.094 D/Cocos2dxActivity: product=otus_reteu_ds
11:49:11.094 D/Cocos2dxActivity: isEmulator=false
11:49:11.099 D/AutoManageHelper: starting AutoManage for client 0 false null
11:49:11.103 D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbau$zza@2efa3200}
11:49:11.106 D/Cocos2dxActivity: onResume()
11:49:11.109 D/AudioFocusManager: requestAudioFocus succeed
11:49:11.187 D/Cocos2dxActivity: onWindowFocusChanged() hasFocus=true
11:49:11.208 V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 360
11:49:11.214 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 2492571
11:49:11.215 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2492614
11:49:11.674 D/cocos2d-x: reload all texture
11:49:11.674 E/cocos2d-x: cocos2d: warning, Director::setProjection() failed because size is 0
11:49:11.706 D/cocos2d-x debug info: Cocos2d-x-lite v1.6.0
11:49:12.411 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1aa in tid 16084 (GLThread 1061)
11:49:12.411 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 16061 (GLThread 1048)
```

I always see these two error logs.

> 11:49:12.411 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1aa in tid 16084 (GLThread 1061
>
> 11:49:11.674 E/cocos2d-x: cocos2d: warning, Director::setProjection() failed because size is 0

I have already tried this but does not work.

[cocos2d-x game crashes when entered background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11008141/6891563)

Comment: You should share your code. You can debug the c++ code in android studio.

Comment: Okay i will try debugging c++ code